# Pass a parameter through onclick in react with condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an onClick with a condition but have an issue when trying to pass with a parameter.

The reason I want to do this is because inside the TableRow I have button that is only visible on desktop. But when people are on 900px and below I want to make it possible to click the entire row. The IsDesktop returns true or false depending on wether the user is over or under 900px

```
<TableRow hover key={site.id} onClick={isDesktop&&(e)=>handleSubmit(e,site.url)}>
  <TableRowSite site={site} index={index} />
</TableRow>
```

This is what I have tried so far. But it keeps giving me an error.

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" (31:67)
```

I have seen several tutorials using a condition in the onClick but never with a parameter but I believe it is possible as it makes sense.

Comment: Use conditional rendering if its desktop render desktop version otherwise render mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally return an undefined handler

```
<TableRow
  hover
  key={site.id}
  onClick={isDesktop ? (e) => handleSubmit(e, site.url) : undefined}
>
  <TableRowSite {...{site, index }} />
</TableRow>
```

Or conditionally invoke the `handleSubmit` callback

```
<TableRow
  hover
  key={site.id}
  onClick={(e) => isDesktop && handleSubmit(e, site.url)}
>
  <TableRowSite {...{site, index }} />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try to do something like this:

```
<TableRow hover key={site.id} onClick={isDesktop ? (e) => handleSubmit(e, site.url) : undefined}>
```

Otherwise, you're simply trying to pass a Boolean value to an event handling prop that's expecting a callback which is seemingly what the issue at hand is caused by.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix you your component looks like

```js
<TableRow hover key={site.id} onClick={isDesktop&&((e)=>handleSubmit(e,site.url))}>
    <TableRowSite site={site} index={index} />
</TableRow>
```

Simply wrap everything after the && in parentheses. That said, there's probably a better way to tackle this by rendering a desktop version or mobile version depending on the screen size of the user